# Opera inserts unwanted tiles into my speed dial

Tags: opera, advertisements

Opera Browser v51.0 inserts parasite advertisement tiles into its speed dial at random moments of time. Is there some way to stop it from doing this?

May be by blocking some URLs or IP addresses?

I am pretty sure it is a built-in behaviour of Opera. My old Opera Mobile 12.0 on Android phone behaves in exact the same way.

Comment: You likely have spyware or an unwanted plugin installed. Check those and remove where necessary.

Comment: @LPChip: I am pretty sure it is a built-in behaviour of Opera. My old Opera Mobile 12.0 on Android phone behaves in exact the same way.

Comment: @Paul Using the same profile syncs both the wanted stuff (bookmarks, history, saved authentication, etc.) but also any malware and/or rogue plugins across all instances of the software and regardless of the OS. So, not a built-in behavior. mine does *not* do such a thing.

Comment: I noticed the same on my Opera after updating. My guess is that the companies "advertised" via Speeddial tiles paid Opera. I remember one tile was from booking.com. Nothing to worry about. It's just bad practice by them

Comment: @nixda: The question is: do they download the advertisement or it is built-in into Opera. In the first case I could block some addresses in firewall.

Answer (score -3):

This just happened to me.  They added booking.com as a tile - I have never even visited the booking site, or any similar site.  Seems to me like something they have implemented.  Makes Opera no different to the others if that is the case, and I may as well go back to Chrome

Comment: Paul, I realise your the self appointed forum police, but the rules clearly state that anyone can ask or answer a question. Nothing in there about that comment meeting your approval.  You might want to ensure Opera adds that in there.